# Return to application when email sent - iOS Javascript Apache Cordova Mailto

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, mailto, kendo-mobile

I have managed to send an email easily by using "mailto". Here is an example of my code:

```
window.location='mailto:test@email.co.uk?subject=Order Acknowledgement&body='+ " confirming";
```

The problem im having is that when I click send in outlook on the iPad, it doesnt go back to my application. I understand why this may not be possible but has anyone got any ideas? I would like to do this without needing to contact the server if possible. I have looked at custom plugins such as "email composer" but the documentation seems to be limited and opon trying to use this, it doesnt work. This may be because I am using Cordova version 3.2.0 and icenium has changed the way their plugins work. Im not sure

Thank you

Comment: did this ever answer your question?  If so it is best to mark as accepted to help others that may have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Have gotten email working for many apps using this plugin - [Email Composer](https://github.com/whodeee/email-composer)

Basically just install the plugin from this location and then use the appropriate code to call up the email composer within your app `window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(callback,subject,body,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,isHtml,attachments,attachmentsData);` an added feature is this plugin also offers the ability for attachments if needed.

Comment: Would you mind briefly explaining how to install the plugin just incase I have missed something please. Thank you for your answer

Comment: are you creating the project using the Cordova CLI?  if so just run the command `cordova plugin add https://github.com/whodeee/email-composer`

Comment: yes, I am creating a kendo mobile application in Icenium Graphite, I have tried to do that command but it says "current working directory is not a cordova based application"

Comment: i think i can now run functions from the js file but it does nothing when it gets to "cordova.exec", have I done anything else wrong? Its to be detecting it because I did a console.log in the simulator and it came up, maybe crashing within it? Should it reach this function "_didFinishWithResult" because it didnt

Comment: in order for the command to work, the project needed to be created using the CLI, otherwise you will the "current working directory is not a cordova based application"